# Getting data from another entity

Tags: java, json, spring-data-jpa

I have to add a new user using a post method. If the locName provided by the user exists in the location_table, the locName and its corresponding state in the location_table will be considered in the new user record which will be saved in the user_table. The code for this is in the else statement below.

```
@Component 
public class UserManager{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository uRepo;
    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository lRepo;
    
    @Transactional
    public void save(UserDto u){        
        User user = new User();
                 Location location = new Location();
    
        if(!lRepo.existsByLocName(u.getLocName())){
             user.setBatchNum(u.getBatchNum());
             user.setLocName(u.getLocName());
             user.setState(u.getState());

             location.setLocName(u.getLocName());
             location.setState(u.getState());    
        }
        else{
             user.setBatchNum(u.getBatchNum());
             user.setLocName(u.getLocName());
             user.setState(l.getState ()); // How do I turn this l in “l.getState()” into      
                                           // a variable for Location so I can get the State of
                                           // that Location entity (not in UserDto)?
        }       
        lRepo.save(location);
        uRepo.save(user);
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Do you want location data selected from u.getLocName when lRepo.existsByLocName is true?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a method to `LocationRepository`, which will return the location state by username, and then use it as arg of `user.setState(...)`.